# Canvas element as overlay to canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

TL;DR How to make canvas element with images to be overlay of second canvas with image.

I have two canvas elements. First one has image of t-shirt. Second one has images which can be added manually. I want to make second one to be overlay of first canvas.

js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('first');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = '#fff';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://neilhem.github.io/dressfor/images/raw-00.png';
image.onload = function() {
  context.save();
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawCustomLogo(context);
}

function drawCustomLogo(context) {
   var layerCanvas = document.getElementById('second');
   var layerContext = layerCanvas.getContext('2d');
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = 'http://neilhem.github.io/dressfor/images/forest/pattern.png';
   image.onload = function() {
      context.save();
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 265, 265);
   }
   context.globalCompositeOperation = 'overlay';
   context.drawImage(layerCanvas, 100, 70);
}
```

I did some example in http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/JdGZKx

As you can see overlayed image is lighter, how to make result not so light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `source-atop` type from the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property.

Also, in your code, you never use your second canvas so I removed it

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('first');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://neilhem.github.io/dressfor/images/raw-00.png';
image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawCustomLogo(context);
}

function drawCustomLogo(context) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = 'http://neilhem.github.io/dressfor/images/forest/pattern.png';
  image.onload = function() {
    context.save();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="first" width="547" height="646"></canvas>
```

Ps : you may also want to change
`context.fillStyle = '#FFF';`  to `context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';`

Comment: I want that second canvas to be overlay image for first canvas. Like here http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/pJgKep In this example pattern is visible only inside shirt

Comment: http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/pJgKep This is what I want to achieve, just one difference when I use image as overlay image it becomes too light.

Comment: My bad, check the edit, I hope I finally got it, I'm kind of tired and your code was really not clear for me